How to make execute/query in mysql2 return array instead of mysql.QueryResult
I've written this test query:
      const [results] = await connection.execute(
        `
          SELECT * FROM providers WHERE id IN (${ids.join(',')})
        `,
      );

However it returns mysql.QueryResult. And given that this array may contain thousands of records, I don't want to do this ridiculous JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)).

try query instead of execute

Destructure the result of the operation using:
import { RowDataPacket } from 'mysql2/promise';

interface Provider extends RowDataPacket {
    id: number;
    // Other Provider properties
}

const [providers] = await connection.execute<Provider[]>(`SELECT * FROM providers WHERE id IN (${ids.join(',')})`);

After this, providers is array and contains the result of the query execution.
You can iterate over the values of an array:
for (const provider of providers) {
    console.log(provider.id);
    // your code here
}


Why do you iterate over providers? The problem is that what is yielded as rows is not iterable, that's to say, it's not an array...it won't even compile throwing the Type 'QueryResult' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. error.

Array.isArray(rows) returns true though. I guess it's because of the union type they used...I ended up doing this: for (const r of rows as unknown[]) {         console.log(r['id']);       }

@Alex, I'm sorry, I didn't know you were using TypeScript. I already updated answer for typescript version.
